# pythonを2からへ3に変更するやり方

Tags: python

すごく初歩的な質問となり申し訳ございません。
osはwindowsです。
python3.6.2をインストールしたのですが、python -vをすると、python2.7.～と表示され、python3が使えません。
qittaなどを見てみたのですが、どうすればよいか分からず質問しました。

Comment: pythonのインストールの手順を追記していただきたいのと、PATHの設定はしましたか？実施したのであればそれも追記していただくと回答が付きやすいかと思います。

Comment: `python3 -v` と実行するとどうなりますか？

Comment: 2.x系が要らないなら、両方アンインストールして、3.x系を再インストール。共存させたいなら、こちらの記事を参考に(版数は読み替えて)。[WindowsにPython2.7とPython3.7が共存できるようにインストールする](https://qiita.com/segur/items/23f276320216c3aa7cf7)、あるいはAnaconda環境なら[【Anaconda】WindowsでのPython 2.7系/3.x系共存環境構築](https://meltingrabbit.com/blog/article/2017091702/) か [Windows10 にAnaconda を入れてPython 2系と3系の共存が簡単にできた](https://qiita.com/ykeiko/items/bf7743adb7c229fa82f4) を参考に。